# SalesTax challenge

Tags: f#, finance

This is the same [problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/531/review-request-salestax-problem?rq=1), but I decided to do it using F#. I'm just interested in how I can improve it.

```
namespace SalexTaxes

module Product = 

    type ProductType = 
        |food = 1
        |book = 2
        |medical = 3
        |other = 4

    type Product =
        {Name : string;
        Type : ProductType;        
        Price : decimal;        
        IsImport: bool}

    let Tax rate price = (price : decimal) * rate
    let BasicTax = Tax 0.1m
    let ImportDuty = Tax 0.05m 

    type ShoppingCartItem =
        {Item : Product;
        Quantity: int}
        member x.BasicTaxes = 
            match x.Item.Type with
                | ProductType.food | ProductType.book | ProductType.medical -> 0.0M
                | _ -> BasicTax(x.Item.Price)
        member x.ImportDuty =
            match x.Item.IsImport with
                | true -> ImportDuty(x.Item.Price + x.BasicTaxes)
                | _ -> 0.0M

    module Order =

        let price (recit : List<ShoppingCartItem>)  = 
            recit |> List.sumBy (fun x -> x.Item.Price) 

        let taxes (recit : List<ShoppingCartItem>)  = 
            recit |> List.sumBy (fun x -> (x.BasicTaxes + x.ImportDuty)) 

        let PrintRecit recit =             
            recit |> List.iter (fun x -> printf "%s: %M\n" x.Item.Name (System.Math.Round((x.Item.Price + x.BasicTaxes + x.ImportDuty),2)))
            let totaltax = System.Math.Round((taxes recit),2)
            let total1 = (price recit) + (taxes recit)
            let total = System.Math.Round(total1,2)
            printf "Total Taxes %M\n"  totaltax
            printf "Total %M\n"  total


    namespace SalexTaxes
    open System
    open Product
    open SalexTaxes

    module Program = 

        [<EntryPoint>]
        let main (argv :string[]) = 

            let prod1 = {Name = "book"; Type = ProductType.book; Price = 12.49m; IsImport = false} 
            let item1 = {Item = prod1; Quantity = 1}
            let prod2 = {Name = "music CD"; Type = ProductType.other; Price = 14.99m; IsImport = false} 
            let item2 = {Item = prod2; Quantity = 1}
            let prod3 = {Name = "chocolate bar"; Type = ProductType.food; Price = 0.85m; IsImport = false} 
            let item3 = {Item = prod3; Quantity = 1}

            let order =  [item1; item2; item3]

            Order.PrintRecit order

            Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

            0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type ProductType = 
    |food = 1
    |book = 2
    |medical = 3
    |other = 4
```

This is how you create an enum in F#. But a more idiomatic way would be to create a discriminated union:

```
type ProductType = 
    | Food
    | Book
    | Medical
    | Other
```

This will also mean that you won't wrote `ProductType.food` to use it, but just `Food`.

---

```
let Tax rate price = (price : decimal) * rate
```

`let` functions are usually named in lower case. And you don't need to specify the type of `price` here, it will be inferred from usage:

```
let tax rate price = price * rate
```

But if you want to specify the type of the parameter, I think it's more common to do that on the parameter side:

```
let tax rate (price : decimal) = price * rate
```

---

```
BasicTax(x.Item.Price)
```

There is no reason for those parentheses here, a more common way to write this would be:

```
basicTax x.Item.Price
```

---

```
0.0M
```

A shorter way to write that is just `0M`.

---

```
match x.Item.IsImport with
    | true -> ImportDuty(x.Item.Price + x.BasicTaxes)
    | _ -> 0.0M
```

Instead of pattern matching on a `bool`, you can use `if`:

```
if x.Item.IsImport
then ImportDuty(x.Item.Price + x.BasicTaxes)
else 0.0M
```

---

```
let price (recit : List<ShoppingCartItem>)  =
```

What does `recit` mean? Is it French? A typo for receipt? Or some abbreviation?

Also, `List` is usually spelled `list`.

---

```
module Program = 

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main (argv :string[]) =
```

You can avoid all this boilerplate code. The code of `main` can be directly at the top level of the file, if you remove the `namespace` declaration (and fix your `open`s).

Comment: yes, should be receipt, misspelling.

Comment: I have 2 files and main in second. So I can remove [<EntryPoint>] if I remove namespace? What do you mean fix open s?

Comment: @Alex You `open` `Product` before `SalesTaxes`. With the `namespace`, `open`ing `SalesTaxes` is unnecessary. If you remove the `namespace`, you will have to correct the order of the two `open`s.