# Printing job task

Tags: c#

Now I have task very similar to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110474/salestax-problem-c-version):

> Job is a group of print items.  For example, a job can be a run of
>   business cards, envelopes, and letterhead together.
>
> Some items qualify as being sales tax free, whereas, by default,
>   others are not.  Sales tax is 7%.
>
> Also applies a margin, which is the percentage above printing cost
>   that is charged to the customer.  For example, an item that costs $100
>   to print that has a margin of 11% will cost:  item: $100 -> $7 sales
>   tax = $107 job:  $100 -> $11 margin total: $100 + $7 + $11 = $118
>
> The base margin is 11% for all jobs this problem.  Some jobs have an
>   "extra margin" of 5%.  These jobs that are flagged as extra margin
>   have an additional 5% margin (16% total) applied.
>
> The final cost is rounded to the nearest even cent.  Individual items
>   are  rounded to the nearest cent.
>
> Write a program that calculates the total charge to a customer for a
>   job
>
> Samples:
>
> Job 1: extra-margin envelopes 520.00 letterhead 1983.37 exempt
>
> should output: envelopes: $556.40 letterhead: $1983.37 total: $2940.30
>
> Job 2: t-shirts 294.04
>
> output: t-shirts: $314.62 total: $346.96
>
> Job 3: extra-margin frisbees 19385.38 exempt yo-yos 1829 exempt
>
> output: frisbees: $19385.38 yo-yos: $1829.00 total: $24608.68

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public namespace PrintJob
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const decimal TaxRate = 0.07m;
            const decimal MarginRate = 0.11m;
            const decimal ExtraMarginRate = 0.16m;

            var job = new Job();
            job.ExtraMargin = true;

            job.Items = GetItemsList();

            foreach(var item in job.Items)
            {
                if (item.Exempt)
                {
                    item.Tax = 0.0m;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Tax = item.Price * TaxRate;
                }
                if (job.ExtraMargin)
                {
                    job.Margin += item.Price * ExtraMarginRate;
                }
                else
                {
                    job.Margin += item.Price * MarginRate;
                }
                job.TotalPrice += item.Price + item.Tax;                
            }
            job.TotalPrice += job.Margin;
            job.PrintReceipt(job);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IList<JobItem> GetItemsList()
        {
            return new List<JobItem>
            {
                new JobItem {Name = "envelopes", Price = 520.00m, Exempt = false},
                new JobItem {Name = "letterhead ", Price = 1983.37m, Exempt = true}
            };
        }
    }

    class Job
    {
        public IList<JobItem> Items { get; set; }
        public bool ExtraMargin { get; set; }
        public decimal Margin { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }           
        public void PrintReceipt(Job job)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job Receipt");
            foreach(var item in job.Items)
            {                   
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:  {1} ", item.Name, Math.Round((item.Price + item.Tax),2));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total: {0} ", Math.Round(job.TotalPrice,2));
        }
    }

    public class JobItem
    {        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }        
        public bool Exempt { get; set; }
        public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    }

}
```

PS. Updated solution you can see on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexan1/PrintJob/tree/master/PrintJob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked and refactored. Updated [here](https://github.com/richseviora/PrintJob).

Here's my high-level observations. I'm in a rush right now or I'd elaborate more, but let me know what you'd like clarified and I'll get back to you?

### Business Data vs. Presentation

Your `Job` type originally had `PrintReceipt` as a member. I moved that out because the `Job` is a business object and should know as little as possible about the presentation layer as possible.

Any application doing anything generally has classes that represent the concepts being managed. These are business objects/models, and they store information. As a general rule, business objects should not have any system specific code (like printing a receipt). This allows us to use the business objects in different contexts without having to recreate them.

You can [read more about clean architecture here](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

### Feature Envy

Because the total price is a property of the `JobItem`, that value should be a property of the object. Similar as with `Job` and the `TotalPrice` value. You'd want to avoid calculating them outside of the class unless there's some compelling reason to do so. This stops your code from getting tangled, and keeps related methods together.

### No Interfaces

Interfaces are good. They help you unit test your code. I haven't written them but they are much easier to test with mock objects (using the `Moq` package, as an example) when you program to interfaces.

I didn't do it, but you should also implement interfaces for the `Job` and `JobItem` classes.

### Need Separated Functions

I've split the file loading, job deserializing, and receipt printing functions into separate classes. This makes it easier to update those items later, if necessary.

As an example, I realized as I was extending this explanation that I had forgotten to change how text is output! Changing those few lines was much quicker than changing it all over the place.

### Using Console to Write Text to File

Since you're going through the effort of instantiating the `FileStream`, I don't see any value in using the `Console.WriteLine` command after changing Output and Error endpoints.

I've left the UI component alone, but that should also be isolated into its own function.